# How to format ExtJS treegrid cell based on value in another cell

Tags: extjs, treegrid

I am trying to format one ExtJS treegrid cell based on the value in another cell in the same row. Below is an overview of how I currently have it coded. However, this is not currently working so I would appreciate any suggestions.Thanks!

```
function fn(v, values){
    if (values.alarm == 1) {
        return '<span style="color: red;">' + v + '</span>';
    }
    return v;
}

//new treegrid

columns:[{
    header: 'H1',
    width: 60,
    dataIndex: 'duration1',
    align: 'center',
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
        '{duration1:this.doFormat}',
        {doFormat: fn()}
    )
}, {
    header: 'A1',
    width: 60,
    dataIndex: 'alarm1',
    align: 'center'
}]
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `doFormat` be just `{doFormat: fn}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution I developed to get what I needed in case anyone else has the same issue.

```
//Treegrid formatting function
function fn(v, values){
    i = i + 1;
    switch(i){
        case 1: x = values.alarm1; break;
        case 2: x = values.alarm2; break;
        default: alert("x not assigned value");
    }
    if (x == 1) {return '<span style="background-color: red; width: 100%">' + v + '</span>';}
    else if(i == currenthour)
        {return '<span style="background-color:' + currentcolor + '; width: 100%">' + v + '</span>';}
    else
        {return '<span style="background-color:' + basecolor + '; width: 100%">' + v + '</span>';}  
}

//create the treegrid
columns:[
        {header: 'Name',dataIndex: 'name',width: 210},
        {header: 'H1', width: 60, dataIndex: 'duration1', align: 'center',              
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('{duration1:this.doFormat}', {doFormat: fn})},
            {header: 'A1', width: 0,dataIndex: 'alarm1' , visibility: false},
        {header: 'H2', width: 60, dataIndex: 'duration2',align: 'center',
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('{duration2:this.doFormat}', {doFormat: fn})},
            {header: 'A2', width: 0,dataIndex: 'alarm2' , visibility: false},
]
```

Comment: wondering if you can help me out?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058921/configuration-required-to-get-sencha-extjs-treegrid-example-working

Answer (score 0):

The ExtJS tree grid is a bit unusual in that it isn't really supported, and is not expected to be fully supported until ExtJS 4, and, in addition, the XTemplate documentation is a bit lacking.

You may have better luck with the following template format:

```
tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('{[this.doFormat(values.duration1)]}', {
    doFormat: fn
})
```